# chrome extension - how to force videos to load with html5 instead of flash

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

I'm building a chrome extension that relies on the existence of an HTML5 video. I've discovered that certain websites load an html5 video on mobile and a Flash video player on web. I'd like to force the website to render the html5 version instead of the flash player. I'd also prefer not to change the entire surfing experience (I could change the user agent to a mobile one but that would change the entire website's layout).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the source code of [html5ify](https://github.com/lenniboy/html5ify), it aims to remove the use of Flash media on websites when there is a better **HTML5 version available**.

The basic idea would be analyzing sites case by case, sending request to HTML5 source if current page is Flash and there are available HTML5 resources.